# How can i upload contents of a folder to server on android?

Tags: android

I figured how to upload a single image using this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMUGyIjV8Yw) video but now im trying to figure out how to upload ALL the pictures in a specific folder in a single motion, without selecting and sending them individually. Some previous questions asking about a similar problem haven't got a clear and/or working answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you are taking about how to upload folder it means you have to create a folder and upload files one by one.

Comment: Show your code to upload one file.